# Can you set and pass any information to the *standard automatic* exception handling process to be included in the exception?

Tags: c#, exception, unhandled-exception

In any Method, can you set anything that will automatically be picked up in the exception handling process?

The following will bubble up the ErrorMessage and the original Exception to the calling programs.

```
void Main()
{
    string ErrorMessage = "FooBar";

    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ErrorMessage, ex);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to replicate this without a Try/Catch/Re-Throw?

Question restated:

Is there any way to have it (in any way) automatically pick up something I designate with the Exception?

```
void Main()
{
    string ErrorMessage = "FooBar";
    throw new Exception();
}
```

So I understand the concept of throwing a new exception with more information.  I am interested in finding a way that when an exception occurs, it takes custom information ("FooBar") with it automatically, and it returns what the Try/Catch/Re-Throw accomplishes, without the Try/Catch and the Re-Throw.

** EDITED **

When the Exception naturally generated without re-throwing reaches the errorHandler, I'd like to be able to retrieve my ErrorMessage (say in ex.data?) which would have "FooBar" in it.

```
void ErrorHandler(Exception ex)
{
    Log(ex.Data); // ex.Data is set to "FooBar";
}
```

"How would the exception system know which custom data you would like to have included in the exception?"

This is the basis of my question.  What can I use that it CAN know?  :P

Another thought to help express what I'm looking for:

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public CustomException() { }
    public CustomException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public CustomException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set;}
}

void Main()
{
    CustomException cEx = new CustomException {ErrorMessage = "FooBar"}; 
    throw new Exception();  // This would be any arbitrary error, not one I'm throwing...
}
```

Then in the ExceptionHandler event, perhaps override the creation of the new exception as in:

```
if (cEx != null)
{
    // Use cEx in place of new Exception() as the error to fill to send
}
else
{
    // Use new Exception() as the error to fill to send
}
```

"It seems to me that you might be confusing logging with exception management - it looks like the info you're wanting to gather automatically would normally be a part of your logging strategy."

OK, let's say you are right.

So, I don't want to log every time I come in, I just want to log the information when a random error occurs.  Let's say I want to know the VALUES of any incoming Parameters as they came in and before they had a chance to change.

The StackTrace of the error will tell me the Method Name and the names of the Parameters and the TYPES of the Parameters.  All good.

But I can find no way to GET the VALUES that were passed in, because one, they aren't available that I can find, and two, they may have changed since they were sent in.

Obviously I could ensure I don't change what came in, but that doesn't help if I can't get to the values anyhow.

Maybe solving this will solve my question in how we process errors.

So now the alternate question would be "How do I log the values of any incoming Parameters ONLY on an Exception?"

I was probably too specific in my question (I don't ask many questions here, I'm still learning the interaction here.) Perhaps I should have asked:

If I wanted to have an error message composed of:

```
"Error in myAssembly.GetStudentName(27)"
```

where 27 is an int (perhaps StudentID), how could I do it without Try/Catch/Rethrow?

I can create a string of

```
"Error in myAssembly.GetStudentName(27)"
```

coming in to every method.  What I cannot do is get that string on any exception without a Try/Catch and do anything with it.

Comment: Can't you just create a custom exception type? `throw new MyException("FooBar");` I don't understand what you mean by "automatically". Are you saying if you had something like `int.Parse("won't parse");`, the resulting exception would include some arbitrary data you defined somewhere?

Comment: I can add a new exception with my information and throw it, yes, IF I wrap my code in a Try/Catch and rethrow.

When any exception occurs, I'd like it to automatically add information I set coming in to the method, no Try/Catch needed or used.

Comment: "Are you saying if you had something like int.Parse("won't parse");, the resulting exception would include some arbitrary data you defined somewhere?"

*Yes!*

And how do you highlight parts of your comments here, I don't see a formatter...

Comment: How would the exception system know which custom data you would like to have included in the exception?

Comment: That is the basis of my question here.  What can be set up to HAVE it know?

Comment: @newby Thats the point - what should it know, and why do you want to "make it know" by anything else than using a custom exception or rethrowing?

Comment: I simply want to set a string inside a method that the value of that string is automatically included in the exception somewhere.  

Using a custom Exception as I understand them, would require me to THROW that custom Exception, thus it is not automatically picking out a random exception and taking along my message.

Comment: At a minimum, I need to set the information at the beginning of the Method.  I may need to update that information as the method runs.  With no Try/Catch and upon an Exception, I need that information to be included somehow in the Error Exception.  Automatically.  Somewhere.

Comment: It seems to me that you might be confusing logging with exception management - it looks like the info you're wanting to gather automatically would normally be a part of your logging strategy.

Comment: Answering you in the Question..  Too long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to avoid writing error handling logic everywhere.

I found the best way for me to solve this using lambda and wrapping this lambda with some generic logic.

Consider the following:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using static ConsoleApp.RuntimeUtility;
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Test();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void Test()
        {
            Run("Error", () =>
            {

                throw new Exception("Exception");

            });
        }

        public static int Test2()
        {
            return Run("Error", () =>
            {

                throw new Exception("Exception");

                return 0;
            });
        }

        public static Task Test3()
        {
            return RunAsync("Error", async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                throw new Exception("Exception");
            });
        }

        public static Task<int> Test4()
        {
            return RunAsync("Error", async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                throw new Exception("Exception");
                return 1;
            });
        }
    }

    public class RuntimeUtility
    {
        public static void Run(string errorMessage, Action action, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            try
            {
                action();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(errorMessage + " from method " + name, e);
            }
        }

        public static T Run<T>(string errorMessage, Func<T> action, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            try
            {
                return action();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(errorMessage + " from method " + name, e);
            }
        }

        public static async Task RunAsync(string errorMessage, Func<Task> action, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            try
            {
                await action();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(errorMessage + " from method " + name, e);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<T> RunAsync<T>(string errorMessage, Func<Task<T>> action, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            try
            {
                return await action();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(errorMessage + " from method " + name, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the logging on the very top level, and everywhere else I use the Run method which wraps the lambda with exception handling logic, and I can pass any data to the Run method so that it can be used in case of exception.

And there is also couple of things which allow to write less code - [CallerMemberName] attribute which will have caller method name; also `using static`.

**Upd:** Added examples for returning value and for async/await.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I will be testing this out completely so I understand it.  THANK YOU.  The biggest part are out Utility classes which are a separate part from our ap and we do use it static-ly.

Comment: So far the only issue is returning values from the method this is placed in.  Here, Test is a void,  But if it were some value, I believe that value would have to be initialized before the Run() call, set inside the Run() call, and returned outside the Run() call.  Correct?

Comment: @newby it can be implemented the way you say, but it is better to have a Run method overload for functions that return the value. And I also use another couple of methods for handling async functions. I will update the answer with an example.

Comment: I wish there was a way to "Super-Like" this answer.  It is genius.  If I could buy you and your what's in your Utilities Library a drink.... :P 

Thank you for your help.  I should post here what my ultimate solution was, based on your help.

Comment: @newby Thank you, I'm really glad to hear that)) and I'm happy to help))

Comment: So, I don't suppose there is a way to take this code and 'Inherit' it in each Method I create so I don't have to put this code in every method, just the inheritance notation?

Comment: @newby no, because for every method you will need a separate method to inherit from(but there are options to simplify this). The closest solution would be using here decorator pattern, I think. I will update examples later.

Comment: @newby you can check it here https://github.com/arsanov/error-handling-samples/blob/master/Readme.md

Comment: I love the decorator method.  I am playing with it and think I will have a bit of a mod to it, and will have to share it.

Comment: I use StackOverflow for getting answers mostly already solved, but I could not find these answers and Viktor got me as close as I think the C# language will allow.  But I may have been too detailed in the question than I should have been?

Would it be helpful to restate what we worked out in new "Question/Answers" in a more concise way, like: 

1) 'How to include incoming parameters to a Method in your ErrorHandler Information Gathering'
2) 'How to run your Method with a common 'Inherited/Decorated' Try/Catch'

Linking here with attributes to the Answer, or does that screw things up?

Comment: Viktor.  Unless I am doing something wrong in the Decorator, it does not handle Dynamic parameters well...

Comment: And cannot handle/use in/out, ref parameters.